# Replacing the duplicate uuids across multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to replace the duplicate UUIDs from multiple files in a directory. Even the same file can have duplicate UUIDs.

I am using Unix utilities to solve this.
Till now I have used grep, cut, sort and uniq to find all the duplicate UUIDs across the folder and store it in a file (say duplicate_uuids)

Then I tried sed to replace the UUIDs by looping through the file.

```
filename="$1"
re="*.java"
while read line; do
    uuid=$(uuidgen)
    sed -i'.original' -e "s/$line/$uuid/g" *.java
done < "$filename"
```

As you would expect, I ended up replacing all the duplicate UUIDs with new UUID but still, it is duplicated throughout the file!

Is there any sed trick that can work for me?

Comment: Are you wanting to keep the original value and only replace the duplicate?

Comment: Its not required to keep the original value.  I am using Mac OS, so in sed it is mandatory to keep the backup of file hence using sed -i".original"..

Comment: Actually you can in-place edit a file on `macOS` version of `sed` also, like `sed -i '' 's/string/replace/g' file`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

duplicate_uuid=$1
# store file names in array
find . -name "*.java" > file_names
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a file_list < file_names

# store file duplicate uuids from file to array
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a dup_uuids < $duplicate_uuid

# loop through all files
for file in "${file_list[@]}"
do
    echo "$file"
    # Loop through all repeated uuids
    for old_uuid in "${dup_uuids[@]}"
    do
        START=1
        # Get the number of times uuid present in this file
        END=$(grep -c $old_uuid $file)
        if (( $END > 0 )) ; then
            echo "    Replacing $old_uuid"
        fi
        # Loop through them one by one and change the uuid
        for (( c=$START; c<=$END; c++ ))
        do
            uuid=$(uuidgen)
            echo "         [$c of $END] with $uuid"
            sed -i '.original' -e "1,/$old_uuid/s/$old_uuid/$uuid/" $file
        done
    done
    rm $file.original
done
rm file_names
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways this can likely be done. Taking a multi-command approach using a function might give you greater flexibility if you want to customize things later, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkdupes() {
    files="$*"
    for f in $files; do
        filename="$f"
        printf "Searching File: %s\n" "${filename}"
        while read -r line; do
            arr=( $(grep -n "${line}" "${filename}" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } ; {print $1" "}') )
            for i in "${arr[@]:1}"; do
                sed -i '' ''"${i}"'s/'"${line}"'/'"$(uuidgen)"'/g' "${filename}"
                printf "Replaced UUID [%s] at line %s, first found on line %s\n" "${line}" "${i}" "${arr[0]}"
            done
        done< <( sort "${filename}" | uniq -d )
    done
}

checkdupes /path/to/*.java
```

So what this series of commands does is to first sort the duplicates (if any) in whatever file you choose. It takes those duplicates and uses `grep` and `awk` to create an array of line numbers which each duplicate is found. Looping through the array (while skipping the first value) will allow the duplicates to be replaced by a new `UUID` and then re-saving the file.

**Using a duplicate list file**:

If you want to use a file with a list of dupes to search other files and replace the `UUID` in each of them that match it's just a matter of changing two lines:

Replace:

```
for i in "${arr[@]:1}"; do
```

With:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
```

Replace:

```
done< <( sort "${filename}" | uniq -d )
```

With:

```
done< <( cat /path/to/dupes_list )
```

> <sub>**NOTE**: If you don't want to overwrite the file, then remove `sed -i ''` at the beginning of the command.</sub>

Comment: This did not work out of the box! But I think I can make it work.